# Why does $\deg p(x)=2$ in this older question about finite extension of $\Bbb R$

Tags: field-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field

I was reading this [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607874/prove-that-every-finite-extension-field-of-bbb-r-is-either-bbb-r-itself-or) and at some point the OP says "Surely $\deg (p(x))=2$ since otherwise it would be reducible."

Why is that true?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you already know (or, at least, what you're logically allowed to assume). For instance, if you know that $\Bbb C$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$, then it's because an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ gives rise to an algebraic extension of degree at least $n$, and any algebraic extension of $\Bbb R$ is either trivial (i.e. just $\Bbb R$ itself again) or $\Bbb C$ (which has degree $2$).

If you *don't* know this, then what you're looking for is a proof of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra). There are several proofs just in that wikipedia article, and there are many more around. It's one of those theorems mathematicians like to come up with new proofs for.

Comment: It's not obvious to me

Comment: @JohnCataldo I realized that it wouldn't be obvious to everyone, so I removed that word. Exactly which part of my first paragraph is it that you cannot follow?

Comment: Thanks for the personalized answer! ...I feel like using the fundamental theorem of algebra implies that we know for a fact that there aren’t any extensions of $\Bbb R$ of degree $>2$.

Comment: @JohnCataldo Well, then. In that case, the second paragraph of my answer is for you. There are many proofs of the FTA, you just pick your favourite. Once the FTA is proven, you do know for a fact that there are no extensions of degree $>2$, since that's exactly what the FTA says.

Comment: @Arthur As you probably know,  FTA was the subject of Gauß's p hd thesis.  He had a number of different proofs (at least $7$, maybe more than $10$, can't remember for sure).  I've thought about asking for people's favorite proofs on this site, and how many they know, but have yet to go through with it ...